# Dynamically create static variables in a class

Tags: ruby

I have the following class:

```
class A
  X = %w(a b c)
end
```

How can I create a list of static variables for class `A` using the values in `X` so that I will end up with the same thing as:

```
class A
  a = 1
  b = 2
  c = 3
end
```

I found out that methods can be defined with `define_method`, but I don't quite have a clue on how to do this for variables.

Comment: Never used a local variable inside a class like this. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What is a static variable?

Comment: I am trying to refactor some variables which act as an enum.

Comment: Could you give a more detailed example? How are you going to access / use these variables?

Comment: I am going to access them with `A::a`; am I missing something obvious?

Comment: `A::a` is something completely different than what you have. What you have in your post are local variables. Local variables go out of scope as soon as the class definition ends, they cannot be accessed anywhere else. What you have in your comment is a method call: you are calling method `a` on class `A`. That's a totally different story, and *much* easier to do.

Comment: Maybe a constant would be more appropriate, i.e. `A::A`, `A::B` and `A::C`

Comment: Sorry, I think I have confused you (and myself). They are constants, as @Stefan suggests. I need to define them on class declaration, then use them wherever needed, their value won't change.

Comment: Can you give us some context? How is it to be used?

Comment: Whats preventing you from doing `class A; A = 1; B = 2; end`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constants are defined like this (they have to start with an uppercase letter):

```
class A
  A = 1
  B = 2
  C = 3
end

A::A #=> 1
A::B #=> 2
A::C #=> 3
```

To define them dynamically, use [`const_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-const_set):

```
class A
  %w(A B C).each.with_index(1) { |c, i| const_set(c, i) }
end
```

Comment: This is what I was after. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, what you want is AFAIK impossible. You simply cannot introduce local variables into a scope dynamically. You might be tempted to do something like this:

```
class A
  X = %w(a b c)
end

class A
  bnd = binding

  X.each.with_index(1) do |var, i|
    bnd.local_variable_set(var, i)
  end
end
```

But that won't work. When you use `local_variable_set` to create a *new* variable, that variable will only exist within the `Binding` object, not in the scope from which the `Binding` was created.

```
class A
  bnd = binding

  X.each.with_index(1) do |var, i|
    eval("#{var} = #{i}", bnd)
  end
end
```

This won't work either. In fact, it is simply equivalent to the first.

Okay, so you think: "let's not use a `Binding`, then, just plain `eval`":

```
class A
  X.each.with_index(1) do |var, i|
    eval("#{var} = #{i}")
  end
end
```

Nope, this doesn't work either. The local variables *still* only get created inside the `eval`, but they don't leak outside. (They *did* leak in 1.8 and older, but they don't anymore in 1.9+.) And in fact, even if they did get created, they would get created in the scope of the block. So, you would have to use `for`/`in` instead.

Also note that even *if* you managed to inject local variables into the scope, they are still local variables: you cannot access them from anywhere else. (Unless you somehow manage to get hold of the `Binding` and call `local_variable_get`.)

It would make *much* more sense to make them methods, which is much easier:

```
class A
  X.each.with_index(1) do |var, i|
    define_singleton_method(:var) do i end
  end
end
```

Now, they can also be accessed from outside the scope:

```
A.a # => 1
```

or using the somewhat obscure method calling syntax using the scope resolution operator:

```
A::a # => 1
```

Of course, since they always return the same value anyway, why not make them constants?

```
class A
  X.each.with_index(1) do |var, i|
    const_set(var.upcase, i)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

With some meta programming madness you could do something like

```
  class A
    class << self
      def A.X(args)
        puts "Creating methods"
        args.each do |arg|
          define_singleton_method(arg) {
            if class_variable_defined? "@@#{arg}"
              class_variable_get("@@#{arg}")
            else
             nil
            end
          }
          define_singleton_method("#{arg}=") { |val|
            class_variable_set("@@#{arg}", val)
          }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Would allow you to do like this

```
  class A
    X %w(a b c)
    A.a = 1
    A.b = 2
    A.c = 3
  end
```

Need to prefix with A.a, A.b and so on because of some ruby syntax thing